# IP setting in CentoOS 6.2x64 by XenCenter 6.2

Tags: networking, linux-networking, xenserver, centos6.2, ipconfig

I have setup a Guest CentOS virtual machine in Xenserver.. I have updated the Xentools but i cannot find the option to config my IP Address which is showing to be 'unknown' currently. All i need to do is assign an IP address to this centOS VM.

Please note that the pool is already created and other virtual machines are already running with different ip assigned..
Xenserver version 6.02
CentOS version 6.2

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the IP in CentOS.

As long as the tools are installed, XenServer will then detect the IP address that you set in the operating system.

Here are a few articles from a quick Google search:

[CentOS Network Configuration Online Documentation](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-network-config.html)

[How2CentOS.com -- Configure Network](http://www.how2centos.com/centos-configure-network/)